# Reading SQL/XML Exported from MovableType

Tags: mysql, movabletype

Is there a way to read the XML files exported from MT? When I open up the XML file, it isn't XML. It's just a string of encrypted characters. I'm looking to bring the SQL contained in it into a custom project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glyph, you are not supposed to import the movable type exported .xml files to your mysql database.

The exported movable type .xml file is a result of the movable type "backup" function. You could use it to restore your blog inside the same or inside another movable type installation, but using the "restore" function.

As you know, the 'Backup' feature is available at the blog level, under:
Tools -> Backup

Or at the system level, under:
System Overview -> Tools -> Backup

However, the "Restore" function is available only at the system level under:
System Overview -> Tools -> Restore

Answer (score 1):

The XML exports are normally perfectly readable. Usually they are compressed either with Gzip or ZIP, are you sure you aren't looking at a compressed file?

Comment: It's not compressed. It started as .gz, but I used 7zip to extract the XML file. This is actually exported from SquareSpace, which uses the MT platform. When I try importing it to SQL it throws a SQL syntax error. But it shows relevant info in the SQL error, so I know it's being read somehow.

The support for SquareSpace is terrible, not getting any help there.